# Android Studio Error "Cannot resolve method for method .add"

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio

I know this question is asked a lot, but I am genuinely stumped, I have looked at other methods, and tried everything... 
My coding problem is as follows, I have a public class in java, and I made a string array in the global scope. I tried to add to it using array.add("somestringhere"), but it spits out an error saying (the title)... One more thing to note is this class is inside the main class for the file. so let's see if I can show it here:

```js
public class see_schedule_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
.
..
.
.
.

// you can make this class as another java file so it will be separated from your main activity.
    public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



        final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";
        // set your json string url here
        String yourJsonStringUrl = "http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxphp";
        // contacts JSONArray
        JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            try {

                // I have a intent passed from teh main class
                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                String[] tasks = extras.getStringArray("tasks");


                // instantiate our json parser
                JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();

                // get json string from url
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);

                // get the array of users
                dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("schedule");

                // loop through all users
                for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable

                    activityid = c.getString("activityid");

                    String yesno = c.getString("yesno");
                    String start = c.getString("start");
                    String stop = c.getString("stop");
                    String plusminus = c.getString("plusminus");


                    Log.e("Hash Map", "Routine ID #" + activityid);
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(activityid) && TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(activityid)) {
                        routine = hm.get(Integer.valueOf(activityid));
                    } else {
                        routine = "";
                    }
                    // TODO: Make the PHP work with a variable residentID
                    //TODO: only make a string if the yes is checked
                    //TODO: make the routine name

//                    Log.e(TAG, "Value for yesno:" + yesno);

                    if (c.getString("yesno").equals("Yes")) {
                        schedule = routine + " starts at " + start + " and ends at " + stop + " with plusorminus " +
                                plusminus + " minutes ";
                        tasks.add(schedule);// This lines yeilds the problem
                        Log.e(TAG, "" + schedule);
                    }

//                    // show the values in our logcat
//                    Log.e(TAG, "activityid: " + activityid
//                            + ", yesno: " + yesno
//                            + ", start: " + start
//                            + ", stop: " + stop
//                            + ", plusminus: " + plusminus);


                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),see_schedule_activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("tasks_filled",tasks);
                startActivity(intent);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {
        }
    }
```

I would appreciate any help, I'm a newb to programming and android studio, and php..so yeah thanks in advance, Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tasks` is an String array as you defined

```
String[] tasks = extras.getStringArray("tasks");
```

And Array doesn't have any `add` method.
You need to convert `tasks` to a list like following

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(tasks);
```

Then you can use `list.add(schedule)`

Comment: wait so what woudl be the equivlent of .add?

Comment: nevermind, you cant add to a list, i have to make a list string then conver it to a string array ty man!

Comment: I cant mark your answer for "6 minutes" i will do it after then, thanks md!